# Drag/Drop feature in Android studio not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, drag-and-drop, fragment

I'm new to android programming The drag/ and drop feature in android studio is not working. I can't drag anything to my phone. Right now my fragment is  google map view  and i want to add a search bar to the view. It just doesn't drag. When I try to add it in text it says element item not allowed here?

This is my activity_maps.xml file

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: Create a container layout around your `MapFragment`, for example a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` and then use that layout to position the `MapFragment` and your search bar as you like.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

the new version of android studio uses 2 xml files for each layout. One (e.g. content_main.xml) embedded in the other one (Activity_main.xml).
you should open the content_*.xml and do the design in it.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to Hamed's answer I also had to:

`File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`

I'm missing vim.

Answer (score 20):

The drag and drop feature is not working in Android Studio.... I also wasted a lot of time searching...what fixed my problem was to select a Theme for the Activity.

The image below will make things clear.
[image]

Comment: I sort of had the same issue. What it worked for me was that i change the theme for NoActionBar and then when i drag and drop any control it works! Don't know exactly why this happens

Comment: I just realize that the content_main.xml file is the one that allows you to drag and drop control over it. I think i just need to get use to android studio...

Answer (score 10):

After updating to the latest version of Android Studio (2.2) I started having this problem.

After some searching and playing around I discovered holding down alt allows my to drag and drop. I had the "hold ALT to drag and drop" option checked under Settings-> Appearance & Behavior > Appearance.

[image]

Either I had already selected this option and a fix in Android Studio 2.2 made it so the option applied to dragging and dropping with the palette panel OR this option was recently added and defaulted to checked or a problem happened while upgrading that set it to true.

I have this option set in IntelliJ and have used the android studio palette normally before and am mostly sure I used it without having to hold down alt before so I'm going with option A (and it took me an embarrassing amount of time until I tried holding down alt).

Comment: Upon seeing your answer I immediately remembered that I checked that damn box 2 days ago...after trying all other answers. Thanks

Comment: @fernan I also checked that damn box and completely lost that feature. :D

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using `ConstraintLayout` in Android Studio 3.0. Fixed it by using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your "values" folder
and open the "styles.xml" file.
Replace "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" under the parent tag with "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem also and I simply fixed that by changing the theme to DeviceDefault.Light for the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Even though the design panel is visible as well as the Palette and Component Tree I ALSO need to have app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml selected over in the Project panel in order for the actual design of the layout to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. The culprit was that in my parent 
    android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
tag i was dragging the components directly but when i put
    FrameLayout
inside 
    android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout 
tag and then drag my components to
    FrameLayout
it worked .

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but not being able to drag elements into the design just happened to me (2/18/18).  Restarting Android Studio (3.01) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem of not dragging elements in `Android Studio 3.1`.

**Restarting the Android Studio**, fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Drag 'n' Drop may not work properly, when you have a LinearLayout, in that condition, the items you drag will try to settle in a specific manner(Horizontal or Vertical), instead try to change your main layout to Relative Layout

> Linear Layout --> Relative Layout

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old issue,none of these were working for me, and it so happened that it wasn't android studio that was giving this problem it was windows. I  noticed I couldn't drag anything so clicking and holding any file on the desktop and pressing escape is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by simply rebuild my android studio project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem,but then I found the solution .
All you have to do is select the element you want to add(eg. Button) and press "Enter".
The component will be displayed on your screen.

Or you can select the component and right click -> Add to Design

Answer (score 0):

I have did everything in this post, until I've run android studio by just running and not running with "Run As Administrator"(Right Click -> More -> Run As Administrator). I've used to run android studio with "Run As Administrator" and that caused the problem to not drag and drop. **Just run Android Studio without "Run As Administrator".**

Or try do vice versa and actually "Run As Administrator" if you already just running it without "Run As Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

File>Settings>Appearance and Behavior>Appearance>Theme -> IntelliJ Light

Change your settings to the above path. Then you can drag and drop  the views on the design view.

Answer (score -1):

I was also confused with the drag&drop feature.  Until I figured out:

After beginning to drag you have to release the mouse button and everything works fine.

Nice feature - a bit unusual though.

Comment: which mouse button should i release? the on that i pressed before drag or another one? please help. this confused me.

Answer (score -1):

I just downloaded Android Studio and ran into this problem.
After clicking random buttons for a few minutes I found out:

There's a magnet icon in the toolbar right above the design view called "Disable Autoconnection to Parent". After I clicked this I was able to move the button wherever.