# How to Copy/Paste views in Component tree in Android Studio IDE

Tags: android-studio, view, copy-paste

I can't figure out how to copy a single view, or whole table row (basically no type of view).

When I right click any of the views in the figure below, there is copy option. But I never get the paste option. Keyboard Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V does not work either.

[image]

I googled for a while, but nothing seems to answer my problem. The closest related post I found [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892479/drag-drop-feature-in-android-studio-not-working).
So is this Copy/Paste bug spread over most of the GUI designer of AS, or what am I doing wrong ?

Android Studio 2.2.2.  @ Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I can drag and drop, but just can't multiply - could it be related to the requirement of unique view ids in the IDE ?

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: I can COPY / PASTE in Android studio 1.5 But, iit is not working in Android studio 2.23, Any solution?

Comment: @salihkallai
My solution ?
Use Eclipse :-) I've had enough of unfixed long lasting bugs in AS..
http://pissedoff-techie.blogspot.sk/2016/01/why-android-studio-sucks-over-eclipse.html

Answer (score 3):

We can always copy/paste in text mode. Seems like that is only solution left for now. And works fine..

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug with Android Studio.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228677

Answer (score 0):

I hold CTRL key then click the view which I want to copy then release.

I found that in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228677

that Alex Leonov shared
here is a photo
[android 2.2 component tree copy and paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xyIS.gif)