# Build Simple User Interface using Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, graphical-layout-editor

I have downloaded and installed Android Studio 4.0 on my Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.5 Everything seems to be working fine except when I try to build a simple User Interface using the Android Studio Layout Editor. When I try to drag and drop a View from the palette into the Layout Editor, it doesn't stay there. Has anyone experienced this problem, and if so how did you resolve it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain in greater detail what "it doesn't stay there" means?

Comment: Take a look at this link [Drag/Drop feature in Android studio not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892479/drag-drop-feature-in-android-studio-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

By default it creates ConstraintLayout and you should add bounds to the view. You can find all required documentation here https://developer.android.com/